# Easier way to assign MySQL table values to variables

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know if there is an easier way to assign all my different columns to a variable. I have over 70 to check if a user has earned a specific song. This is a shortened version of the code. I haven't done all the songs yet and I was wondering if there is an easier way.

```
$results = mysqli_query($con,"Select * FROM users WHERE user_name ='$username'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
$userpoints = $row['points'];
$intro = $row['intro'];
$fightingfires = $row['fightingfires'];
$may = $row['may'];
$crowdedstreet = $row['crowdedstreet']; 
}
```

Comment: Explain your question clearly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup, use php extract() http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Here is a simple example:

```
$results = mysqli_query($con,"Select * FROM users WHERE user_name ='$username'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
extract($row);
}
// This will give you variables for each item
// so you will get $points for what would have been $row['points'], etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Look at the other people's examples on using `extract()` which does similar stuff to the foreach loop that I have here:

Try using variable variables:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
    foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
        $$column = $value;
    }
}
```

For each row, essentially you'll be loading variables that have the same name as the column name. It would be like doing:

```
$points = $row['points'];
$intro = $row['intro'];
$fightingfires= $row['fightingfires'];
$may = $row['may'];
$crowdedstreet= $row['crowdedstreet'];
```

..etc

Basically, "points" is the name of the first key, and the variable gets the name "points" so you get variable `$points`.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: it worked thank you, I had a different name for results in my code so thats why it didn't work orginally, you just saved me so much time, especially when I expand my catalog

Comment: I got two working answers, you answered first, can I accept two answers, how does it work? I am new to the site

Comment: @MichaelStClair I definitely won't turn down an upvote on my answer although I think Jordon's answer is more elegant than mine, so you should accept that person's answer (you can only accept 1 answer per question). But thanks Jordon for the education!

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as doing

```
extract($row);
```

Your loop will look something like

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
    extract($row);
    echo $intro;
}
```

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/extract)